# Infinite scrolling implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to do lazy loading during onscroll. Below is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(   
            function() {


                if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200) && !loadNews))

                {
                        loadNews = true;
                        loadMoreNewsItems();

                }
            });
```

LoadMoreNewsItems() does AJAX call and appends the data, on success of AJAX call am setting loadNews flag to false again.

Is the above implementation correct. I have subtracted 200 because of footer block available below newsitems.

When we check, sometimes the user has to scroll till the footer for loading more newsitems. Am checking this on mobile device. What could be the probelm here.

And, sometimes when we scroll fast there are multiple AJAX requests. But, I have added the loadNews flag for avoiding that. But, it does not work either.

Please help.

Comment: You have an extra bracket in the if statement `&& !loadNews))`. Please fix it first.

Comment: it is just copy paste of code. I removed unnecessary code. Oops, i am looking for solution here, not syntax issues.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Comment: Dont want to use a library for this. Is this not possible by only js code. Already am using some libraries like swipe.js which has made the client side to be thick

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to do infinite scrolling

```
var d=document;
var remainingHeight=d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight - (d.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);

if(remainingHeight < 500){
     //do the loading process
}
```

You should give it a try instead of your current test, it should fix your problem with the mobiles.

Also, about the multiple ajax request and your flag, the problem is that && !loadNews is not placed correctly in your test, it is in the wrong set of parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide the correct syntax. AM getting $(document).scrollHeight as undefined, infact all values as undefined when i debug

Comment: myriacl-Can you please let me know what is the issue here.

Comment: Can anyone help on this issue.